# Pygame animation now showing on screen

Tags: python

In my game there is an animation of "exploding" when the ship hits something and loses 1 hp. This is the code that triggers `self.first_player_ship.explode()`:

```
 def _first_player_ship_hit(self):
    """Respond to the first player ship being hit by an alien."""
    if self.first_player_ship.exploding:
        return

    if self.stats.ships_left > 0:
        self.first_player_ship.explode()
        self.first_player_ship.shield_on = False
        self.settings.thunder_bullet_count = 1
        if self.settings.first_player_bullets_allowed > 1:
            self.settings.first_player_bullets_allowed -= 2
        self.stats.ships_left -= 1

        self.first_player_ship.center_ship()
        self.sb.prep_hp()
    else:
        self.stats.player_one_active = False
        if self.stats.player_two_active:
            self.first_player_bullets.empty()
        else:
            self.stats.game_active = False
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
```

The problem is that the animation works well until the player loses his last hp. The ship just disappears without the animation playing.
I suspect that it might have something to do with the update method in my game, when the ship loses all it's hp becomes inactive, and when it's inactive it's not blitted on the screen anymore.

```
def _update_screen(self):
    """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
    if self.stats.player_one_active:
        self.first_player_ship.blitme()
```

In the _first_player_ship_hit(self), I tried to put the first_player_ship.explode() before setting the inactive flag to False but it still didn't work.

Link to game repo: https://github.com/KhadaAke/Alien-Onslaught

Comment: I'm sorry, but the problem is not reproducible. Please edit the question and add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please focus on **minimal** and **reproducible** and do not just paste all your code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your analysis is correct. One solution could be to make the animation not depend on the existence of a ship or a player. Another to introduce a "dying" state and not remove the ship until it's over. And there are probably others.

Comment: It is impossible to reproduce the problem with the code given in the question.

Comment: I added the link to the game repo.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have found a solution for my problem, I will post it here.
I created these two methods (the ones for the other ship are similar):

```
def _thunderbird_ship_hit(self):
    """Respond to the Thunderbird ship being hit by an alien, bullet or asteroid."""
    if self.stats.thunderbird_hp >= 0:
        self._destroy_thunderbird()
        self.thunderbird_ship.set_immune()

def _destroy_thunderbird(self):
    """Destroy the thunderbird ship then center it."""
    self.thunderbird_ship.explode()
    self.thunderbird_ship.state.shielded = False
    self.settings.thunderbird_bullet_count = 1
    if self.settings.thunderbird_bullets_allowed > 1:
        self.settings.thunderbird_bullets_allowed -= 2
    self.stats.thunderbird_hp -= 1

    self.thunderbird_ship.center_ship()
    self.score_board.create_health()
```

And I modified my method that draws the ships on screen like this to check if the ship's hp is < 0 and is not in the exploding state before setting the alive state to False.

```
def _draw_game_objects(self):
    """Draw game objects and the score on screen."""
    for ship in self.ships:
        # Check the state of the Thunderbird and Phoenix ships and update their "alive" state.
        if ship == self.thunderbird_ship:
            health = self.stats.thunderbird_hp
        else:
            health = self.stats.phoenix_hp
        if health < 0 and not ship.state.exploding:
            ship.state.alive = False
        # Draw the ships on screen only when alive.
        if ship.state.alive:
            ship.blitme()
```